# Good practice .Net Core API validation

Tags: c#, clean-architecture

So lets say we have a `AccountController`

And has a method like this for registering:

```
    [HttpPost("register")]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterDto user)
    {
        try
        {
            accountService.Register(user);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

For registering, your `EmailAddress` must not be used and `Password` must meed a criteria

The validation exists inside `accountService` and does something like this:

```
    public void Register(RegisterDto user)
    {
        accountValidator.ValidateRegistration(user);
        accountHandler.Register(user);
    }
```

Notice the `Register` method is void, so it does not return anything, and the method `ValidateRegistration` looks like this

```
    public void ValidateRegistration(RegisterDto user)
    {
        if (accountRepository.UserExists(user.Email))
        {
            throw new ExistingAccountAssociatedWithThisEmailAddressException();
        }
        if(!Regex.IsMatch(user.Password, passwordRegex))
        {
            throw new PasswordDoesNotMeetCriteriaException();
        }
    }
```

I am throwing exception with specific name so I can pass this back to the view, but I am wondering what is the best way to do something like this ? Creating specific `Exceptions` and throwing them ? I dont want to pass a string back

Comment: Do not use void with async, return Task.

Comment: this is off-topic for stackoverflow. personally, I'd prefer returning status of operations and other relevant details instead of throwing exceptions. your catch block does not filter on your exception types. so if any other exception occurs, you won't be able to trace it in logs

Comment: It was a mistake to keep it in there sorry, I removed all Task/async, as I am interessted in the best approach with validation and returning message/validation errors

Comment: FluentValidation lib https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/index.html may be a good orientation for common concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Using specific exceptions is a good practice, in my opinion, as they explain better a developer's intentions.

I can recommend two ways that may help refine your code:

- Let all input-related exceptions inherit from a base exception named for example "BadInputException" (or "DomainException", from the perspective of clean architecture). This way you can catch the base exception then return BadRequest back to client.
- Use asp.net core's middleware to handle such exception ([here's an example](https://medium.com/@antarikshverma/how-to-handle-errors-with-the-inbuilt-middleware-in-asp-net-core-web-api-7c5aab0ec7ca)), instead of try/catch block in every action. This way you would make your code cleaner.